# What to do with `usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address`?

Tags: usb, dmesg, 14.04

I found it in dmesg of my Ubuntu 14.4.02 notebook. I wonder if should take actions.

```
~ > grep "usb 3" dmesg
[    2.475970] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.476450] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[    2.680655] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[    2.884158] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 2, error -71
[    3.052272] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    3.054039] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[    3.256858] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[    3.460406] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[    3.628593] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    3.630174] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[    3.832966] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[    4.036642] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[    4.148704] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    4.149213] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[    4.353366] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[    4.556965] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[    4.669047] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    4.690089] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0745
[    4.690116] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.690140] usb 3-4: Product: Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0
[    4.690159] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Microsoft
```

Here my usb devices

```
~ > lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:58c2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What is your problem? Does everything work OK?

Comment: Yes, seems everything work

Comment: So nothing is to worry about.